# Program does not enter while loop

Tags: java, jdbc

I'm creating a web application. I'm using netbeans 7.4 and MySQL 6.1 for my database. I want to change the user's password. The structure of the password that is saved in the database is in md5. So, I have to convert the user's input for current password into md5 first and check the database if there's any match. Right now, I have a form structure in my ChangePassword.jsp. In the form are three fields for the current, new and retype password. Then through a servlet, I am manipulating these pieces of information.

The connection to the database is fine and I can already manage to encrypt the current password into md5. But, when I added a `while(rs.next())` loop in my program to loop for all the results of my query, it doesn't work. So it won't forward to the desired jsp. Any suggestions on how I can do this? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance. This is my code.

```
try{
            ServletContext context = getServletContext();

            String currentPassword = request.getParameter("currentPassword");
            String newPassword = request.getParameter("newPassword");
            String tryNewPassword = request.getParameter("retypePassword");
            String pswrd = "";

            //For Password Encryption into md5
            String md5 = null;
            MessageDigest digest = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            digest.update(currentPassword.getBytes(), 0, currentPassword.length());
            md5 = new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16);

            //Database Connection
            Class.forName(context.getAttribute("dbdriver").toString());
            String db = context.getAttribute("connstr").toString();
            Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(db);
            Statement stmt = conn.createStatement();
            stmt = conn.createStatement();

            //Check Database Connection
            if (conn != null) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Connected!");
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Not Connected!");
            }

            String query = "SELECT password FROM accounts WHERE password='"+md5+"'";
            ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery(query);


            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Entering while loop");
            while(rs.next()){
            if(md5CurrentPasswrd.equals(rs.getString(1))){
                if(newPassword == tryNewPassword){
                    digest.update(newPassword.getBytes(), 0, newPassword.length());
                    md5NewPasswrd = new BigInteger(1, digest.digest()).toString(16);
                    String queryUpdate = "UPDATE accounts SET password='"+md5NewPasswrd+"' /n"
                            + " WHERE password='"+md5CurrentPasswrd+"'";
                    PreparedStatement prepStmt = conn.prepareStatement(queryUpdate);
                    prepStmt.executeUpdate();

                    response.sendRedirect("/Project1/PasswordSaved.jsp");
                }else{
                    response.sendRedirect("/Project1/PasswordNotSaved.jsp");
                }
            }else{
               response.sendRedirect("/Project1/PasswordNotSaved.jsp");
            }
            pswrd = rs.getString(1);
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Running while loop");
        }

            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "End of while loop");

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChangePassword.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChangePassword.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChangePassword.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

Comment: first thing to do: check whether or not there are actual results to iterate over. if there is no next, it's pretty normal it doesn't enter the while loop

Comment: Next thing to do: stop building SQL like that. Use parameterized SQL instead, and specify value parameters.

Comment: You are using a `PreparedStatement` (good) but are not using the important features of it (bad). If you care just a little bit for the safety of your database please read this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html (edit: Jon beat me to it)

Comment: @Stultuske As you've said, I checked the resultset but it wasn't empty

Comment: Next thing, delete the line `Class.forName(context.getAttribute("dbdriver").toString());` - this has not been needed for about ten years

Comment: have you checked your log file for exceptions?

Comment: @Bohemian I've deleted it. Any reactions why the program still does not go to the while loop?

Comment: @Stultuske there are no exceptions in the log file.

Comment: my advice, re-write the entire thing. it's code like this: if(newPassword == tryNewPassword){ that makes developers who have to maintain code freak out

Comment: just break the loop once redirected.

Comment: @Braj How will I do that?

Comment: add a `break;` statement in the loop just below the redirect statements.